# get a csv file as a http download

Tags: java, servlets, plsql

I have to create a CSV file on a nightly process and avail those files to client as an http download.

I have created a CSV with the help PLSQL block as:

```
DECLARE
    F UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    CURSOR C1 IS SELECT emp_id, name FROM employee;
    C1_R C1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('EXPORT_DIR','employee.csv','w',32767);
    FOR C1_R IN C1
    LOOP
        UTL_FILE.PUT(F,C1_R.emp_id);
        UTL_FILE.PUT(F,','||C1_R.name);
        UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(F);
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F);
END;
/
```

this will create a CSV file "employee.csv" on the database server. Now I have to avail this file to the clients as a HTTP downloadable file. How to do that ?

Comment: where is your files store is it in table ?

Comment: no, its on server side on, stored on the disk with a specific name.

Comment: ok.. than passed that file path to below example. This will prompt user to save or open file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easy to copy the generated file web server. we can just use SCP or FTP to the generated file on webserver. e.g.

```
scp /mnt/csv_dir/feed.csv root@server:/home/stackoverflow/www/csv
```

Add this command in a nightly process to run 
The above command will move the `feed.csv` from csv_dir to csv folder of web server.

now we will be able to access the file using the web url.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide one Servlet to download your file as a `csv` format.

**DoanloadServlet.java :**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
        throws ServletException, IOException {      

try{
     //set content type to csv and response as attachment    
     response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Myfile.csv");
     OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();  

     //read your file from database in outputstream
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int length;
     while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
          out.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
     in.close();
     out.flush();  
  }  
  catch(Exception e)
  {  
    //Exception handling  
  }

}
```

Give user a link and call this servelet with required parameter to find file from database.
You link look like this
`http://serveraddress.com/DoanloadServlet?fileName=name_of_file`